# How to make If … And statement work in Excel to see if a variable equals any of a set of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a Roulette table in excel for a project. I have a random number variable named RandomNumber which generates and stores a random value between 0 and 36 in a cell, which does work. But When i write an if statement to check if RandomNumber equals one of the numbers that would make that bet be a winning bet it does not work. Like in the code below, it allways returns succesfull when it should be false, as it appears that it just sees all of the numbers between all the "Or's".

Sorry for bad english, thanks for any input

I tried several Match and Ranges in the worksheet to make it work.

```
Sub Column_bet_1st()

 Dim PlayerBet As Range, Balance As Range, Bet_input As Range, RandomNumber As Integer

    Set PlayerBet = Range("O21")

    Set Balance = Range("L18")

    Set Bet_input = Range("O18")

    RandomNumber = Int((36 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)

If Bet_input = "Column 1" And RandomNumber = 3 Or 6 Or 9 Or 12 Or 15 Or 18 Or 21 Or 24 Or 27 Or 30 Or 33 Or 36 Then Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2 Else
Balance = Balance - PlayerBet

End Sub
```

Expected results are that the if statement will only look for those numbers as shown in the code and return false if RandomNumber does not equal any of them.

Comment: `RandomNumber = 3 Or RandomNumber = 6 etc`

Comment: You also have a "single" `else`  in your code. The line `Balance = Balance - PlayerBet` will always run.

Comment: Why those useless `-0`and `+0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways I can think of doing it:

Your corrected original code:

```
If Bet_input = "Column 1" And (RandomNumber = 3 Or RandomNumber = 6 Or _
                               RandomNumber = 9 Or RandomNumber = 12 Or _
                               RandomNumber = 15 Or RandomNumber = 18 Or _
                               RandomNumber = 21 Or RandomNumber = 24 Or _
                               RandomNumber = 27 Or RandomNumber = 30 Or _
                               RandomNumber = 33 Or RandomNumber = 36) Then
    Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2
Else
    Balance = Balance - PlayerBet
End If
```

Or, as RandomNumber must be a multiple of 3 to be a win:

```
If Bet_input = "Column 1" And RandomNumber <= 36 Then
    If RandomNumber Mod 3 = 0 Then
        Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2
    Else
        Balance = Balance - PlayerBet
    End If
End If
```

Or using a `Select...Case` statement:

```
If Bet_input = "Column 1" Then
    Select Case RandomNumber
        Case 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36
            Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2
        Case Else
            Balance = Balance - PlayerBet
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: "9 Mod 3" - Oops.

Comment: Yeah, just saw it... oops. :)  Sorry, didn't see the `MOD` version you used in your answer... have an upvote to!

Comment: No problem at all. Stack Overflow works best if there are a selection of answers as we all tend to emphasise different things. Using a `Mod` is really the only sane thing to do.

Comment: Thanks so much, i found out that none worked cause i had a problem with my randomnumber, so i changed some stuff and now this code is perfect, thanks so much for the help! ... i used the case one, as i liked it the best hehe

Answer (score 2):

You need to write

```
RandomNumber = 3 Or 6 Or 9 ...
```

as

```
RandomNumber = 3 or RandomNumber = 6 Or RandomNumber = 9 ...
```

Better still, use `RandomNumber Mod 3 = 0` (checking explicitly if `RandonNumber` is not `0` if that really is a possibility that you don't want). Putting this together you get

```
If Bet_input = "Column 1" And RandomNumber Mod 3 = 0 Then
    Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2
Else
    Balance = Balance - PlayerBet
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

@Magnus Henden could you please try the below code and provide a feedback?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Column_bet_1st()

 Dim PlayerBet As Range, Balance As Range, Bet_input As Range, RandomNumber As Long

    'Refe to specific worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set PlayerBet = .Range("O21")

        Set Balance = .Range("L18")

        Set Bet_input = .Range("O18")

        RandomNumber = Int((36 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)

        If Bet_input = "Column 1" And (RandomNumber = 3 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 6 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 9 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 12 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 15 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 18 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 21 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 24 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 27 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 30 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 33 Or _
                                        RandomNumber = 36) Then
            Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2
        Else
            Balance = Balance - PlayerBet
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```